# unlink($filename) : Permission denied Warning

Tags: php, unlink

I am getting Permission denied waring when i try to use unlink().

I have created i function to delete an image from content directory :

```
function del($fnam){
chmod('content/'.$fnam, 0777);   
chown('content/'.$fnam,465);
unlink('content/'.$fnam);   
}
```

I have used chmod() and chown() after reading from forums , still i am getting that warning and image is not getting deleted.

How ever it runs as charm when i call it from different location.

```
if($temp2==1){      //For Delete
$sql="delete from blog where b_id=$temp1";
$im=fetch('blog','b_img','b_id='.$temp1);

//Deleting Image

    del($im);
}
```

code above is not in any function (running procedural fashion), and this is giving me positive response.
How to fix that?

Comment: you need write permissions on the containing directory to be able to delete a file, since it's the directory file which has to be modified to "delete" a file. and are you SURE you're passing the proper argument to your del function?

Comment: @MarcB yeah i am passing the right argument, because function is working perfectly when i am calling it anywhere else, even if it was argument error it might have popped error for invalid file name or invalid path which it didn't.

Comment: @MarcB how can i modify the file to delete? thanks

Comment: @Ajaz you have shell access or ftp access ?

Comment: I found it , just wrote the whole code again , and worked like magic .lol computers are weird .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this situation you can't remove file with php because php don't have enough permission if you can't change permission from above , try a hack with FTP
(i know its not usual but its works and it can help you for personal usage)

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to delete $file
if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $file)) {
 echo "$file deleted successful\n";
} else {
 echo "could not delete $file\n";
}
```

Comment: its depends to your hosting abilities and permission

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code assumes that the `chmod` and `chown` will always work, this is a bad assumption.

If you dont have the correct permissions they can also fail.

Change the code like this and it should tell you what bit is actually going wrong

```
function del($fnam){
    if ( ! chmod('content/'.$fnam, 0777) )  {
        echo 'chmod failed';
    }
    if ( ! chown('content/'.$fnam,465) ) {
        echo 'chown failed';
    }

    if ( ! unlink('content/'.$fnam) ) {  
        echo 'unlink failed';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the expected results because:

According to the manual [chown](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php):

> **Attempts** to change the owner of the file filename to user user. Only the superuser may change the owner of a file.

It will only work if your application is running as root, which I'm certain that's not the case.

According to the manual [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php):

> **Attempts** to change the mode of the specified file to that given in mode.

Basically, *chmod* and *unlink* won't work if you don't have the right permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing permissions for the content directory

```
function del($fnam){
   chmod('content/, 0777);   
   unlink('content/'.$fnam);   
}
```

Comment: if it cannot delete, i doubt it can change permission.